# How to pass session variable

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm trying to use a Single Sign-on function for a specific script but it's not working. I think the problem is when I try to change between the 2 sessions.

I know about `session_start();` should be on the first line but I don't know how to do that in a function called.

Here the function code :

```
function singleSignOn(){
    session_name('Main');
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['id'];
    session_id('Specific');
    session_start();
    return $username;
}
```

Comment: You can just put `session_start()` on the first line for every `php` file you have and remove it from your function

Comment: once if you define session_start() its enough. you don't have to write it again in the page (even inside the function). write the session_start() outside the function scope and check

Comment: session variables are then available for r/w as array values from $_SESSION superglobal array variable, eg : $_SESSION['foo'], $_SESSION['bar'], as per [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)